# Use "label" or define a pod template in jenkinsfile for kubernetes-plugin?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

### In General

I'm trying to use label when using [kubernetes-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) for Jenkins, but I get a little bit confused.
In my `pipeline` bellow I'm trying to build test job in `parallel` steps with different labels (agents).

I already have configured the plugin with pod template and container in my Jenkins config, where I use same settings as it's in the pipeline `podTemplate` defined.

### Issue

The problem is that when I use `agent label` in stage 2 there is jnpl image running instead the image that I point in the config `someimage:latest`.

In `stage 1` where I define the pod in pipeline there is no problem and the required images are running fine.

### Question

*What I'm doing wrong?*
Here is my `jenkinsfile` and config of the [kubernetes-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) in Jenkins:

```
def podTemplate = """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: k8s
    image: someimage:latest
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - infinity
    volumeMounts:
      - name: workspace-volume
        mountPath: /home/jenkins/agent
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
  volumes:
      - name: "workspace-volume"
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: "jenkins-worker-pvc"
          readOnly: false
"""
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Parallel") {
            parallel {
                stage("1.k8s") {
                    agent {
                        kubernetes {
                            yaml podTemplate
                            defaultContainer 'k8s'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh """
                            mvn -version
                        """
                    }
                }
                stage("2. k8s") {
                    agent { label 'k8s' }
                    steps {
                        sh """
                            mvn -version
                        """
                    }
                }
                stage("win") {
                    agent { label 'windows' }
                    steps {
                        bat "dir"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specified an image for `stage` with `label` `k8s` and `windows`.

You can read in the [docs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) that:

> The plugin creates a Kubernetes Pod for each agent started, defined by the Docker image to run, and stops it after each build.
>
> Agents are launched using JNLP, so it is expected that the image connects automatically to the Jenkins master.

You are using `podTemplate` and I would advice setting up [`container`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/#podtemplate-define-a-podtemplate-to-use-in-the-kubernetes-plugin) , this might look like the following:

```groovy
podTemplate(containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
    containerTemplate(name: 'golang', image: 'golang:1.8.0', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
  ]) {

    node(POD_LABEL) {
        stage('Get a Maven project') {
            git 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin.git'
            container('maven') {
                stage('Build a Maven project') {
                    sh 'mvn -B clean install'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Get a Golang project') {
            git url: 'https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform.git'
            container('golang') {
                stage('Build a Go project') {
                    sh """
                    mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/hashicorp
                    ln -s `pwd` /go/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform
                    cd /go/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform && make core-dev
                    """
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can read more about [Container Configuration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#container-configuration) and [Container Group Support](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#container-group-support)

Comment: Yep...in the first first line of your answer tells everything. Actually I do have agent with `lablel` `windows` My mistake is that I'm trying to take `label` from **Labels** in the **kubernetes-plugin**.